# What is the best way to report the results on an F-test about coefficients in a regression (in a written text)?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, regression-coefficients

I used the method described here to test two coefficients if they are different from each other: https://kzee.github.io/CoeffDiff_Demo.html
I did what you find under "Testing Differences in Coefficients", i.e. using in R the linearHypothesis from the car package.

I wonder what is the best way to report this?

Should I a) make stable out of all the information the test gives or would it be enough to say "the coefficients on var a and var b differ from the linear hypothesis testing(F=20.132, Pr(>F) 8.019e-06, Res.DF 1057)?

Is there any convention?

In case it matters: My model is basically

model <- lm(y ~ -1 + a + b+ c , data = d)
and my test

linearHypothesis(model, "a - b = 0")

Comment: Why "quickest" in the title? Wouldnt "best" be the question you really want to ask.

Comment: That’s a good point! I want best, yeah! And if there are multiple solutions that are equal I would pick those with least characters?